# How to extend auth in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a project with already existing database with users which is slightly different from that scheme Laravel is using. So i need to extend credentials selecting from db and checking function. Basically i need to get username and password from the web, encode it with base64 and check this in db. I manage to find some info here http://laravel.com/docs/extending#authentication, but was not able to understand code for extend.

Comment: You're base64 encoding passwords? That's useless as a security measure.

Comment: @ceejayoz as i said before, i have already existing project, it's not mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a huge security problem by encoding your password with base64.

Extending Auth (Guard) can be tricky, but if you need something that simple, you can do the auth yourself easily:

```
$user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();

if( $user && $user->password == base64_decode(Input::get('password')) )
{
    Auth::login($user); /// will log the user in for you

    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
else
{
   /// User not found or wrong password
}
```

Laravel doesn't really mind what your user model is, you can do it with whatever table you want.

Anyway I advise you to rehash your passwords as soon your user logs in:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
else
{
    $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

    if( $user && $user->password == md5(Input::get('password')) )
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }

}
```

The only requirement is that your User (or whatever you call it) model implements `\Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface` and implement the methods it uses to get the correct data:

```
class Customer implements Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface extends Eloquent {

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return 'Username';
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password;
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        /// this must be implemented to Laravel knows what your data is
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        /// this must be implemented to Laravel knows what your data is
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        /// this must be implemented to Laravel knows what your data is
    }

}
```

What you basically have to do is to reproduce Laravel's User model, changing what you need to change to make it work with your own database table: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php

Comment: Can i specify in laravel config which db connection, table, fields  use?

Comment: You can do it in your model. `$table = 'table_name'`, you can have a model just for auth, or you can specify the connection in the method itself: `User::on('connectionName')->where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();`

Comment: but if i using auth through `Eloquent` can i specify what fields would be `username` and `password` as they are different

Comment: By manually authenticating your users (`Auth::login($user);`), will not mind about fields, just the needed implemented methos of the interface ´\Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface´. Edited to clarify a bit.

Comment: Yes, i understand, but firstly i want to try do it with `Eloquent`. Currently the problem is that in my db fields is `Username` and `Password` and Laravel selects it in lover case.

Comment: But I'm talking about Eloquent, I just forgot to write it in the class. And what I'm trying to tell you is that you can have Eloquent and whatever field names you have in your table, Username, user_name or u_s_e_r_n_a_m_e :)

Comment: Edited again to add Username and Password to the code.